# Get follower id who have more followers

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

In Twitter4j API how to get followers ids who have more followers for themselves ? i cant find any methods in twitter4j API and i tried to use 'PagableResponseList'to fetch 5000 ids per call but this is not feasible to my application.  since the ids im playing with have more than 1000000 followers so im getting rate limit error from API

Comment: What is the exact question, can you give an example and explain??

Comment: @Jhanvi: Is there is any method /way to get followers ids of any user who have more followers count without being rate limited by twitter API using Twitter 4j

Comment: you want the follower ids of a particular user??

Comment: @Jhanvi :gates have 20000000 followers and for example david who follows gates have 4000 followers like wise 
paul - 30000 followers, steve - 45 followers,Sharah - 100000 followers and so on, from Api i can get any user followers ids but i need only followers who have more followers to themself in the above scenario..Sharah and david

Comment: have more followers than steve now i need to get those top 10 from gates followers list for my app, wihtou being rate limit, i can get only 5000 ids per call and store in arraylist and sort them but im getting rate limit error. so looking for an different approach, so basically have to go through all 20000000 followers and get top 10 is this possible ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a shorter way to do this task. It can be broken into following steps:

- Get all the followers of the user, using the API call: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/list.json
- The response to this api call will have a maximum of 200 followers, then have to make the next call on the basis of `next_cursor_str` obtained frm the response of the above mentioned call.
- While parsing the objects of the response in the loop, 3 parameters are to be stored in the list , we can store together in a single string by using any seperator, these parameters are: **id (twitter id of the follower)** , **followers_count(number of followers of this user)** , **name(name of the follower)** .
- Then we can sort this list on the basis of `followers_count` and we can get the desired result.

**Rate limit:** This whole process needs to be broken into certain time period based on a certain schedule , as the rate limit error will occur if the number of followers is more..